# como mostrar una consulta de php en una card horizontal de bootstrap4

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente problema, necesito mostrar en una `Card Horizontal` de `Bootstrap 4` una consulta desde base de datos para mostrar las entradas de un blog sencillo.

¿como hago para imprimir la información traída desde la base de datos en Blog mediante una `Card horizontal` de `Bootstrap`?

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
    include_once("../modelo/drive.php");

    try{
      $myconnect=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=inspirablog', 'root', '');
      $myconnect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      //$myconnect=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=gaxenreh_inspiraBlog', 'gaxenreh_secursoft', 'Ledic@8848999');
      //$myconnect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      $driveObjetos=new driveObjetos($myconnect);

      $tablaBlog=$driveObjetos->getContenidoPorFecha();

      if(empty($tablaBlog)){

        echo "No se encontraron entradas en el Blog!";

      }else{
        
        foreach($tablaBlog as $valor){

          echo "<h3>" .$valor->getTitulo() ."</h3>";

          echo "<h6>" .$valor->getFecha() ."</h6>";

          echo "<div style='width:500px'>";

          echo $valor->getComentario() ."</div>";

          if($valor->getImagen()!=""){

            echo "<img src='../imagenes/";

            echo $valor->getImagen() . "' width='300px' />";

          }

          echo "<hr>";

        }

    }

    }catch(exception $e){

      die("error:" .$e->getMessage());
  
  }

?>

<br>

<a href="../welcome.php"> volver al formulario de entradas del Blog</a>
```

Comment: Escribe una página de html con bootstrap estática con ese tipo de tarjeta (a manera de ejemplo) y luego utiliza el código de la región que se repetirá en las instrucciones echo(); en php, para que generes la página dinámica.

Comment: esta sugerencia yo ya la aplique pero no me da por que como es un blog me debe reproducir la Card tantas veces como registros hayan en la base de datos y de la forma que propones solo aplica una vez, creo que no es funcional, a menos que no le haya entendido su aporte, muchas gracias

Comment: Entonces tu problema no es de frontend, sino de backend. Independientemente del diseño que tengas, sea card o como quieras llamarlo, es un elemento que debería repetirse y eso lo logras únicamente con el backend.

Comment: Buenas noches, finalmente pude con su aporte entender un poco mas la solución aun que no era como usted la propuso, pero si me abrió la mente y le di solución, y se ve perfecto en pc pero en dispositivos móviles no he podido arreglar la apariencia, comparto url para que si me pueden ayudar con el inspector del navegador mirar cual es el error muchas  gracias Url: https://www.inspiracoach.com

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que buscas es hacer algo simple, podes probar algo con este estilo, meter todo el card dentro del foreach y crearlo para mostrar la entrada.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<?php
include_once("../modelo/drive.php");

try{
  $myconnect=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=inspirablog', 'root', '');
  $myconnect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  //$myconnect=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=gaxenreh_inspiraBlog', 'gaxenreh_secursoft', 'Ledic@8848999');
  //$myconnect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $driveObjetos=new driveObjetos($myconnect);

  $tablaBlog=$driveObjetos->getContenidoPorFecha();

  if(empty($tablaBlog)){

    echo "No se encontraron entradas en el Blog!";

  }else{
    
    foreach($tablaBlog as $valor){

      echo "<h3>" .$valor->getTitulo() ."</h3>";

      echo "<h6>" .$valor->getFecha() ."</h6>";

      echo "<div style='width:500px'>";

      echo $valor->getComentario() ."</div>";

      if($valor->getImagen()!=""){

        echo "<img src='../imagenes/";

        echo $valor->getImagen() . "' width='300px' />";

      }

      echo "<hr>";

    echo "<div class=\"card\"><div class=\"card-header\">".$valor->getTitulo()."</div><div class=\"card-body\"><h5 class=\"card-title\">Titulo del post</h5><p class=\"card-text\">".$valor->getComentario()."</p></div></div>";


    }

}

}catch(exception $e){

  die("error:" .$e->getMessage());

}

?>

<br>

<a href="../welcome.php"> volver al formulario de entradas del Blog</a>
```

No te olvides de agregar la librería de Bootstrap.

Saludos.

Comment: Buena respuesta si bien no solucionó completamente mi pregunta si me abrió camino a una mejor solución el cual voy a desarrollar, esperemos me de resultado, muchas gracias por su aporte